# Entities returned by Projection Queries

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm designing an application in which I hope to use projection queries to retrieve Entity objects from the App Engine Datastore to save on latency and cost. I have two questions about this:

1) If one calls the Entity.getProperty(String propertyName) method on a returned Entity where propertyName does not correspond to one of the properties selected for by the Projection, will the return value be null or will Java throw an exception? The Entity documentation doesn't indicate what happens if propertyName does not exist. A corollary, do the not-selected-for properties no longer exist in the returned Entity or do they simply have no or null values assigned to them?

2) Is the Key of the truncated Entity that is returned the same as the Key of the original full Entity that's actually in the datastore? From what I understand, the Key is a hash of the kind, name/id property, and ancestor path of an Entity. Name/id also appears to be a property, so if one doesn't select for it, does the Key of the returned Entity differ from that of the actual Entity?

These questions seem like they would be fairly easy to answer with some testing once I'm up and running, but I'm new to App Engine and am still just designing my project, so I won't be in a position to do so for a while. Was hoping someone out there already knows the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If a property does not exist in an entity, .getPropery() returns null. No exception is thrown.
2. If a property is not named in a projection query, the retrieved entity does not have this property even if the full entity does.
3. The key of an entity returned in a projection query is the same as in any other query. The key is created when an entity is first inserted in the datastore, and it does not change after that.

A little explanation. When you insert a new entity in the datastore, the datastore creates an entity *and*, separately, creates an entry for each indexed property, or a combination of properties (custom index), in a respective index. Projection query is just another combination of indexed properties. It retrieves all the data it needs directly from its own index without retrieving the entity itself.